# Which architecture does dlib's CNN face detector use?

Tags: computer-vision, face-detection, dlib

I tried googling a lot but could not find it. Is it a implementation of some paper published on CNN face detection?

Is there any details on the theoretical part of dlib's convolutional face detector?

Comment: [`This face detector is made using the now classic Histogram of Oriented
    Gradients (HOG) feature combined with a linear classifier, an image pyramid,
    and sliding window detection scheme.`](http://dlib.net/face_detection_ex.cpp.html)

Comment: Aren't the HOG features and CNN features different? I found the description you wrote in this file http://dlib.net/face_detector.py.html but I am wondering about the CNN specifically http://dlib.net/cnn_face_detector.py.html. Am I missing something?

Comment: my bad. [CNN version of MMOD](http://blog.dlib.net/2016/10/easily-create-high-quality-object.html) I think. http://dlib.net/cnn_face_detector.py.html, https://sourceforge.net/p/dclib/discussion/442518/thread/27ec33e7/

Comment: this was very helpful. thank you so much

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It uses a custom architecture.  You can check it in the [source code](https://github.com/davisking/dlib/blob/8fdb3af9bf2a9574bfea6464749c002b543f4f66/tools/python/src/face_recognition.cpp)

```
    ...    

    template <template <int,template<typename>class,int,typename> class block, int N, template<typename>class BN, typename SUBNET>
    using residual = add_prev1<block<N,BN,1,tag1<SUBNET>>>;

    template <template <int,template<typename>class,int,typename> class block, int N, template<typename>class BN, typename SUBNET>
    using residual_down = add_prev2<avg_pool<2,2,2,2,skip1<tag2<block<N,BN,2,tag1<SUBNET>>>>>>;

    template <int N, template <typename> class BN, int stride, typename SUBNET> 
    using block  = BN<con<N,3,3,1,1,relu<BN<con<N,3,3,stride,stride,SUBNET>>>>>;

    template <int N, typename SUBNET> using ares      = relu<residual<block,N,affine,SUBNET>>;
    template <int N, typename SUBNET> using ares_down = relu<residual_down<block,N,affine,SUBNET>>;

    template <typename SUBNET> using alevel0 = ares_down<256,SUBNET>;
    template <typename SUBNET> using alevel1 = ares<256,ares<256,ares_down<256,SUBNET>>>;
    template <typename SUBNET> using alevel2 = ares<128,ares<128,ares_down<128,SUBNET>>>;
    template <typename SUBNET> using alevel3 = ares<64,ares<64,ares<64,ares_down<64,SUBNET>>>>;
    template <typename SUBNET> using alevel4 = ares<32,ares<32,ares<32,SUBNET>>>;

    using anet_type = loss_metric<fc_no_bias<128,avg_pool_everything<
                                alevel0<
                                alevel1<
                                alevel2<
                                alevel3<
                                alevel4<
                                max_pool<3,3,2,2,relu<affine<con<32,7,7,2,2,
                                input_rgb_image_sized<150>
                                >>>>>>>>>>>>;
    anet_type net;

    ...
```

Comment: That's face recognition. Face detector is located in the same folder cnn_face_detector.cpp .

Comment: This network is for face recognition. It's different from face detection.

Answer (score 0):

"**Max-Margin Object Detection**" paper, link from "https://arxiv.org/pdf/1502.00046.pdf"

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).